# How can i attach an event to all my nodes of a DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, nodes, addeventlistener

I just tried to attach all the nodes to a click event. But i can't understand how to add them at the time of `onload`. 
 i just tried to figure out the full path of the node list from the clicked place to the root node.  here is my code, i was unable to identify what to pass as addEvent() parameter.

```
    function addEvent(node){  // i used this function in onload event
        if(node == null) return;
        node.onclick = catchClickedItem;
        for(var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++){
            addEvent(node.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }

    function catchClickedItem(e){
        alert(e.target);    
    }
```

i tried to add the addEvent with this :

```
window.onload = addEvent
```

i faced this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: can you show how do you call your `addEvent()` function?

Comment: `childNodes` also includes `Text` and comment nodes. Do you really want this? Also, “this is not working” is not a problem description.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I´m 100% sure you don´t need to attach an event to all your nodes

Comment: i just tried to check that if it is possible to attach a same event to all the nodes even the text nodes.

Comment: @HackerBoy: Yes, it's possible. And your code does it. (It also does some unnecessary things, like giving `onclick` to Text nodes; but doing that is largely harmless, it wouldn't make the code not work.) You'll have to define "not working" and provide a [mcve] of that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you had some good additional explanations in your answer that I neglected.  Please feel free to edit my answer and add those details there if you'd rather not post another answer.  I was going to add those details and attribute them to you but I can't see your answer now.

Comment: @zero298: I deleted my answer because I realized it doesn't really answer the question, because the OP asked if they could do this and showed code that will do it. So we don't really know what the OP is asking... :-)

Answer (score 1):

Adding an event listener to every single node is a bad idea.  Delegate instead.  Use `addEventListener` instead of `onclick` instead as well.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  alert(e.target.innerHTML);
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<div>
  <div>hello</div>
  <div>
    <div>world</div>
    <div>
      <div>foo</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```